# implement the window.history to iframe

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have navigation menu, based on click of the menus i am loading the respective pages url in src attribute  of iframe tag and also i have two buttons back and forward. On click of it , i need to take back and forward respectively. In this case i cant use history.back(), since am not pushing the url to location object instead am just changing the src attr of iframe. I have attached code snippet for the reference, share your thought on this

```
<button>prev</button>
<button>next</button>
<nav>
 <ul>
  <li><a href="page 1 url">page 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="page 2 url">page 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="page 3 url">page 3</a></li>
 </ul>
 </nav>
```

on click of the menu am just loading the respective page url in the ifranme tag

```
<iframe src="page1 url" />
```

on page load i will landed on page 1 url. if i click on page 2 link i will load the page 2 url in iframe src attr.if user click on prev button i need to take back to page 1 and vice versa. Here i need to keep track of the history of the iframe url. Need a solution using javascript

Comment: You could store their page choices in an array.  Then use `push()` to add each `next` page to the end of the array and `pop()` to get the last page if they choose `prev`

Comment: i need to take forward as well. if i do pop() i will lose the history and unable to take the user forward

Comment: If you use `pop()` you are removing a page at a time - if they click `next` you just `push()` their new choice.  If you want to see a complete history, you could keep their choices on the array (ie, don't use `pop()`) and use an index pointer (a variable) to target the current, next and previous choices.  So, any new page they go to, the index pointer would be pointing at the last item in the array.  If they go back, you move the pointer back one.  If they go forward, you move it up one.  If they go to a new page entirely, you `push()` that onto the array and move your pointer to that one.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I think you could do it.  I'm only using a select list to illustrate the functionality as I can't really link to loads of pages in iframes here.

```js
let history = [];
let pointer = 0;


function newPage() {
  let s = document.getElementById("pages");
  let newPage = s.value;
  history.push(newPage);
  pointer = history.length - 1;
  displayPage();
}

function displayPage() {
  if (history.length > 0) {
    let dp = document.getElementById("pageselected");
    dp.innerHTML = history[pointer];
  }
}

function next() {
  pointer++;
  if (pointer == history.length) {
    pointer = history.length - 1;
  }
  displayPage();
}

function prev() {
  pointer--;
  if (pointer < 0) {
    pointer = 0;
  }
  displayPage();
}
```

```html
<button onclick="prev();">Previous</button><button onclick="next();">Next</button> Page selected: <span id="pageselected"></span>

<hr>
<select id="pages" onchange="newPage();">
  <option value="0">--Select page--</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
  <option value="6">6</option>
  <option value="7">7</option>
  <option value="8">8</option>
  <option value="9">9</option>
</select>
<hr>
```

Pick a `page` from the select list, and the pointer variable is set to that item.  Select another one, and again, the pointer is set to that item.  Now click the `Previous` or `Next` buttons and the pointer variable points to the previous or next item in the array.  Nothing is removed from the array - only new selections from the drop-down list are added.  Thereafter the pointer controls what is displayed - in this example, just the page number to the right of the buttons.